# Setting an entire data() object in vue to populate forms

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this data from mongodb that i am getting this way and receiving it on the client side

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");


$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->hotel->airlines;


$cursor = $collection->find();

echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor));
```

This is a sample of data i get from the server

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "609c51803d59e5004f225a92"
    },
    "added_by": "609c35b4f940b04db90a7222",
    "airline_category": "regional",
    "airline_alliance_category": "star_alliance",
    "airline_logo": [{
        "url": ""
    }],
    "airline_status": "active",
    "airline_summary": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_contact_details": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_name": "Delta",
    "airline_code": "Delta",
    "airline_home_airport": "Denver",
    "airline_office_address": "Dever",
    "airline_country": "United States",
    "airline_city": "Deenver",
    "airline_region": "North West",
    "airline_telephone_number": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_email_address": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_website": "Delta Flies"
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "609c51cc6059021c31781242"
    },
    "added_by": "609c35b4f940b04db90a7222",
    "airline_category": "regional",
    "airline_alliance_category": "star_alliance",
    "airline_logo": [{
        "url": ""
    }],
    "airline_status": "active",
    "airline_summary": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_contact_details": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_name": "Delta",
    "airline_code": "Delta",
    "airline_home_airport": "Denver",
    "airline_office_address": "Dever",
    "airline_country": "United States",
    "airline_city": "Deenver",
    "airline_region": "North West",
    "airline_telephone_number": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_email_address": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_website": "Delta Flies"
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "609c51d91833cc79af668d32"
    },
    "added_by": "609c35b4f940b04db90a7222",
    "airline_category": "regional",
    "airline_alliance_category": "star_alliance",
    "airline_logo": [{
        "url": "\/var\/www\/html\/uploads\/609c51d51227f.jpg"
    }],
    "airline_status": "active",
    "airline_summary": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_contact_details": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_name": "Delta",
    "airline_code": "Delta",
    "airline_home_airport": "Denver",
    "airline_office_address": "Dever",
    "airline_country": "United States",
    "airline_city": "Deenver",
    "airline_region": "North West",
    "airline_telephone_number": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_email_address": "Delta Flies",
    "airline_website": "Delta Flies"
}]
```

On the client side the client data variables look like this

```
export default {
  name: 'Seed_Airlines',
  data() {
    return {
    airlineForm:{},
    added_by:'',
    allusersfetched:'',
    airline_name:'',
    airline_code:'',
    airline_category:'',
    airline_alliance_category:'',
    airline_home_airport:'',
    airline_logo:'',
    airline_status:'',
    airline_office_address:'',
    airline_country:'',
    airline_city:'',
    airline_region:'',
    airline_summary:'',
    airline_contact_details:'',
    allairportsfetched:'',
    record_id:'',
    fetchedid:'',
        }
    },
```

In my mounted, i am calling this code

```
axios.get(fetch_all_airlines)
            .then(response => {   
                console.log(response.data);
                var data = response.data;
                    this.data = data
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            });
```

Since the data returned, contains a hidden id field

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "609c51803d59e5004f225a92"
    },
```

i want to strip `"_id": {` and the other `}`

and be left with `"$oid": "609c51803d59e5004f225a92"` as part of the data object.

How can i set the entire returned data object to populate my forms since it perfectly matches the data object i used to insert data into mongo in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to modify your `data()` method to look like this:

```
data() {
   return {
       apiData: {
           ...yourListOfPropertiesWillBeHere
       }
   }
}
```

Basically, by nesting all your properties one level down, it will be easier to avoid having changes that Vue cannot detect. [Read more about change detection caveats here.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Then, on your API call you will do something like this:

```
axios.get(fetch_all_airlines)
  .then(response => {   
    this.apiData = { ...response.data };
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  });
```

Also, to strip the `_id` you can do it like this:

```
axios.get(fetch_all_airlines)
  .then(response => {   

    const airlines = response.data.map(value => {
        const airline = return {
            ...value,
            "$oid": value._id["$oid"]
        }
        delete airline._id;
        return airline;
    });

    this.apiData = airlines;

  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  });
```

Comment: There is a problem If i want to access a v-model item which `apiData.airline_name` the posted object to the server shall have a key name in the form, `apiData.airline_name` for instance and that is a n error in mongodb. Is there a solution to have this key names without dots.

Comment: Can you show me the POST request? Or some backend code where the mongodb problem is?

Comment: I have fixed that. I put the `apiData.airline_name` to v-modelonly and not to the name. However, on post i cant capture apiData as part of the object, only the data inside https://jsfiddle.net/6c2n1amu/

Comment: I was thinking that the object is persisted something like this https://jsfiddle.net/tn0a6ejm/  so that i store it in mongodb like that but i still get the  non nested result

Comment: this is what is posted `{reviewed_by: "609c35b4f940b04db90a7222", review_item: "609cd3c7746aea5be4537d42", review_content: "hellohellohellohellohello", datetimeofthereview: "2021-05-13T14:22:00.000Z", review_score_given: "4"}` no change than when i just had data(){} only

Comment: Your code for rearranging the oid is not right, but the concept of holding the reactive vars within an encompassing object is right on. I just fetched the id value response.data._id.$oid and set it in a hidden field and its getting posted to the server ready for save() or update.